# White sprite material?

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

So seems like the default colour for `SpriteMaterial` is `0xFFFFFF`. Which seems to mean the sprite has no colour. If I change the colour property of the material to say `0xFF0000` the sprite will appear with a red tint.

What if I want a white tint? How would you achieve this?

Comment: `0xFFFFFF` is exactly "white" and `0xFF0000` is exactly "red" - by "no color" do you mean "transparent"? A "white tint" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Okay so basically what I mean is some kind of brighten effect. The idea is like this, let's say you have one sprite which is made of a bunch of colours, you copied that sprite to a new layer in photoshop, made it just a white blob and then placed it on top of the original sprite and put the opacity to 0.8. Then you would have a "white tint" basically. This is the kind of effect I want to do inside the sprite material.

Comment: It sounds like you want to change the alpha, or opacity of your color.  Some useful [suggested reading](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp) to get you started with a clearer understanding of color codes and how alpha/opacity is specified.

Comment: It's sort of that but it sort of isn't. It's closely tied to how threejs handles sprite materials. I guess the easiest solution for a white tint tween or brightness animation would be to do that in the sprite sheet itself, it's kind of lame though.

Comment: Good luck - you can always try fiddling with the CSS in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p3wunu3a/1/) to get the color effect you're looking for, and that might help you focus your question a bit more so someone else can more easily help with the three.js / sprites part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to make your sprite texture brighter (more white), you can do this by increasing the color over 1.0.
you cannot do this with hex values, instead use this:

```
obj.material.color = new THREE.Color( 2, 2, 2 );//or higher
```

note that 1,1,1 is pure white (grey is 0.5,0.5,0.5), so you go into color values which cant be displayed by the screen anymore, so it is just clipped to white

[reference](http://threejs.org/docs/?q=standard#Reference/Math/Color)

similar to photoshop, there are also different ways to blend your objects
have a look at this example:
http://threejs.org/examples/?q=blend#webgl_materials_blending

additive blending is the best way to go for light flares, etc.

you can check out the code in the bottom left to see how you can apply it to your case.
note that transparency needs to be enabled on your material for these to work

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Okay so the color docs say that it accepts values between 0 and 1, are you saying that if I say, maybe the value `1.5, 1.5, 1.5` it will interpret this as a brighten? Also in terms of blending, I've tried `THREE.AdditiveBlending` out but it makes the Sprite texture transparent which isn't what I'm after.

Comment: as webGL colors are handled as floats, you can go as high as you want, even negative

Comment: That's great to know, I'll try it out and get back right away. The three docs should probably point that out if it works tbh, pretty misleading to say the constructor only accepts a certain range when that statement is incorrect

Comment: if you have p.e. a blueish texture value like '0.2, 0.2, 1.0' and you multiply it by 5, it will be all white with an overbright blue value

Answer (score 0):

I do not code in your environment and without knowing the Blending math nor encoding you are using is hard to help but Opacity/Transparency in sprites is usually defined like this:

1. **By Color with Alpha channel**

   In that case the color has format `0xAARRGGBB` so if you discard the highest `8` bits of color you are setting Alpha to zero which could be full transparency or fully solid material depending on blending equation used. In this case just add the alpha value.

   Sometimes sprite has separate image mask containing the Alpha channel or bit mask instead.
2. **By color in specific pixel position**

   It is usually corner of sprite. So if your sprite is fully filled with single color that means it is fully transparent. This kind of transparency encoding does not know Alpha channels at all so you can not combine colors with other sprites. This kind of sprites got just holes in it (where is the same color as in the specific pixel position). For example Icons use this.

   In this case identify the pixel position for example do a sprite divided into 4 squares each with different color. Which one is not rendered is the corner used for transparency color ...
3. **By specific color**

   In this case one specific color is used as transparent. This color is usually chosen so it is not missing from the palette too much. usually black or white depends on the background or content. In tis case if `0x00FFFFFF` means transparent then you can try to use `0x00FEFEFE` instead (which is the second highest intensity white/graysh shade available)

So identify which one is it and repair your sprites accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It seems as though three has chosen the third method to render Sprite materials correctly. I will give that solution a go and see how it goes.